# SQL Queries Taking Longer When Run Simultaneously

Tags: sql, reporting-services

I'm trying to get to the bottom of why an SSRS report has suddenly started taking 30 or 40 minutes to run instead of 2 or 3, and I've tracked the issue down to the fact that it has multiple Datasets, so runs several queries simultaneously.
There are 5 queries, which individually take 30-90 seconds, and by checking the "Use single transaction when processing the queries" box in the SSRS data source, and hence making it run the queries in series rather than in parallel, I can make it run in around 7 minutes, which makes sense as that is the total amount of time they take individually.

I've not been able to identify any changes to the server which made the performance suddenly deteriorate, but I have managed to distil the problem down to a behaviour which I don't really understand - The simplified example comes down to:

If I run a query against my server it takes a fairly consistent amount of time to run.  But if I run the same query twice at the same time, it takes far longer than twice the time of running it once.
I would expect it to take a period of time which is greater than running the query by itself, but no greater than running it twice.  What actually happens is that one of the queries completes in around 1.5 times the original time, but the other goes on much longer than twice the time.
In fact, in some circumstances, once one query finishes, the other takes considerably long *from that point* to complete than it would if run by itself.  Which I can only assume means that it is taking a while for all resources used by the first query to finish to be released.

I'm struggling to see much in the activity monitor that looks unusual.  Anything I should be checking?!

Comment: Profile trace would be the place I'd start.

Comment: What version of SQL are you using?  What transaction isolation are you using?

Comment: Sounds like a resource issue to me.

Comment: SQL 2016, and Isolation level is read committed

Comment: I'll run a trace and see what I can see

Answer (score 0):

As advised, I've run a profile trace, but I can't see that it tells me much...

[This screenshot is from running the query once (48 seconds to complete)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qAmLo.png)

[And this is from running it twice concurrently (100 seconds for first to complete, 184 seconds for second)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6xmYY.png)

Comment: FYI: you should edit your original question with this update rather than providing it as an answer.